# How can I use a shell wildcard in sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, wildcard, glob

I'm trying to use a shell wildcard in sed. The following fails. (I expect `foo` as output.)

```
$ touch foo
$ ls
foo
$ echo *
foo
$ bar=*
$ echo $bar
foo
$ echo "$bar"
*
$ echo replace | sed "s/replace/${bar}/"
*
$ echo replace | sed "s/replace/"${bar}"/"
*
```

As expected, the penultimate command doesn't produce `foo`, since `${bar}` is (double-)quoted. However, I expected the last command to expand the wildcard.

I *can* get either command to work after the following, though.

```
bar=$(echo *)
```

Further, I would have expected shell wildcard expansion in the following, which does not occur.

```
$ echo replace | sed s/replace/*/
*
```

However, this works.

```
$ echo replace | sed s/replace/$(echo *)/
qwe
```

Comment: thats because `*` alone is not a command but `echo *` is, shell understands `echo *` as a command and substitutes the result with it after that `sed` comes to work.

Comment: Have you tried this command?: `echo replace | sed s/replace/$(echo ${bar})/` (Launching echo in a subshell and its stdout going to your sed command)

Comment: @snyder really? But I don't really see the difference between the command `echo` and the command `sed`. Similarly, you can use `*` in `find`, etc. I thought that bash would just always expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last command does try to expand the wildcard except that it fails. From `man bash`:

```
 Pathname Expansion
        After  word  splitting,  unless  the -f option has been set, bash
        scans each word for the characters *, ?, and [.  If one of these
        characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and
        replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching
        the  pattern.
```

As it says, bash tries to expand each word containing a `*` to matching filenames. In your case, it tries to expand to a filename beginning with `s/replace/` and there is no such file. To prove this:

```
$ echo "aaaa" | sed "s@a@*@g"
****

$ echo "aaaa" | sed "s@a@"*"@g"
****

$ touch s@a@b@g

$ echo "aaaa" | sed "s@a@*@g"
****

$ echo "aaaa" | sed "s@a@"*"@g"
bbbb
```

As for the solution to your problem, you can use subshell expansion as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: To further demonstrate, run `shopt -s nullglob`, then try the last command again. When the expansion fails, the entire argument to `sed` is removed, leaving your command as `echo "aaaa" | sed`, in which `sed` just reproduces its input.

Comment: Great answer! Very clear. Also, it's interesting to note that despite first impressions, my proposed solution and those in the comments are a _non_-useless use of echo. (Also, thanks @chepner, that is also interesting.)

Comment: @Sparhawk `bash` supports `bar=*; foo=replace; echo "${foo/replace/$bar}"`, so there may not be a need for `sed` at all here.

Comment: @chepner I've never come across that within-variable replacement before. What is it called, so I can search more and educate myself? However, this doesn't seem to work for me (i.e. it outputs `*`).

Comment: It's a `bash` extension, documented as "Pattern substitution" under "Parameter Expansion" in the `bash` man page. Quoting the argument to `echo` prevents the `*` from being expanded before it is passed to `echo`. Unquoting it would allow the `*` which results from the expansion to be expanded before `echo` gets it.